# Web Page Posting and Capturing Response using C#

Tags: c#, post, html, httpwebresponse, namevaluecollection

I have a webpage :http://180.92.171.80/ffs/data-flow-list-based/. After Filling Basin Name and River Name from Drop-down Menu, Station Names are appeared in Flood Forecasting Sites, when I select any of them, it automatically redirect to return that station's information. I need to save that information(Name, Date and present Water Level) on regular basis obviously with C#.

I have some knowledge in C#. I have tried some codes on Webpage posting and Name Value Collection but yet not successful.

Codes are:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.yoursite.com");
request.Method = "POST";

formContent = "FormValue1=" + someValue +
    "&FormValue2=" + someValue2 +
    "&FormValue=" + someValue2;

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formContent);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd());
//You may need HttpUtility.HtmlDecode depending on the response

reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Another Code:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://mysite/myform.aspx");
string postData = "item1=11111&item2=22222&Item3=33333";

byte[] send = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.ContentLength = send.Length;

Stream sout = req.GetRequestStream();
sout.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
sout.Flush();
sout.Close();

WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
string returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Can anyone help me in this regard?? It will be a great help for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read data through Jquery by their div or span value